# Solve $\cot^2x=\csc x$ in degrees

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\cot^2x = \csc x$$
I have to solve for $x$ in degrees. Here's what I did:
$$\cot^2x=\csc^2x - 1$$
$$\csc^2x -\csc x - 1 = 0$$
If $y=\csc x$:
$$y^2-y-1=0$$
and now I cannot proceed to the given answers of 38.2° and 141.2°.

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: You may be confusing yourself by using $x$ to mean two different things.  Perhaps "Let $y = \csc x$ so that $y^2-y-1 = 0$...

Comment: Yes still does not reach 38.2, 141.2 using it

Comment: Did you take the reciprocal of the result you get using the quadratic formula, before using the inverse sine function?

Comment: The trig identities that you are using only hold for angles in radians. You must solve the problem for radians then convert your answer into degrees.

Comment: what do you mean by reciprocal

Comment: If you use the quadratic formula, you'll end up finding solutions for a quadratic in $\frac{1}{\sin x}$. You need to turn the fraction upside down (i.e. find the reciprocal), use the inverse sine function, then convert your answer from radians to degrees.

Comment: cheers thanks i got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since $$\frac{\cos(x)^2}{\sin(x)^2}=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$$ you will get $$\cos(x)^2=\sin(x)$$ this means $$1-\sin(x)^2-\sin(x)=0$$
and so you will get a quadratic equation in $$\sin(x)$$

Comment: thank you for the $$-2$$!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I can't understand why this got downvoted and even got a vote for deletion. It is correct and simple.

Comment: Maybe this was downvoted because the author takes a long route of converting $\csc$ and $\cot$ into $\sin$ and $\cos$ when it is not required to...(I didn't downvote)...

Answer (score 3):

$$\cot ^2\left(x\right)=\csc \left(x\right)$$
$$\cot ^2\left(x\right)-\csc \left(x\right)=0$$
Let: $\color{red}{u = \csc \left(x\right)}$
$$-1-u+u^2=0$$
$$\color{red}{\csc \left(x\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\:\csc \left(x\right)=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}$$
$\color{blue}{\mathrm{Solutions\:for}\:\csc \left(x\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$
$$x=2\pi n+\pi -\arcsin \left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right),\:x=2\pi n+\arcsin \left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)$$
$\color{blue}{\csc \left(x\right)=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\quad :\quad \mathrm{No\:Solutions}}$

Solution in decimal form $x=2\pi n+\pi -0.66624...,\:x=2\pi n+0.66624...$
Solution in degress form $\color{grey}{x = 38.1727°, x = 141,8273°}$

Comment: You really shouldn't use "$=$" between two things that are not equal.  For instance, "$\arcsin\left( \dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}} \right) = 0.66624\dots$"  Otherwise, you are claiming that the result is rational, which it is not.